# WebView Component in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, webview, ionic2

I know there are SafariViewController and InAppBrowser to load URL. But both are showing into the new screen. I want to add WebView inside the specific page like how we are adding button into the screen. Is there any way to add webview as a component into the page ?

Comment: You can use iframe to show your web content inside the specific page.

Comment: Did you get any solution yet? I have been looking for the same solution for a long time.